# iOS dynamical height of UITableViewCell and heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm using Autolayout for my new UITableViewCells in a large project.

I've one TableView where the height of each row is calculated automatically, there I don't use the delegate function `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

I've declared a estimated row height:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

My question is: on another TableViewController there are a lot of UITableViewCells, where I programmatically need to declare the height of the cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. I know that It would be better to convert all cell's to use a unique solution, but in this project are a lot of different cell's, so I'd like to use a workaround and combine the dynamically calculated height with autolayout and the programmatically calculated row height.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using iOS 8 and above, you do not need to calculate height dynamically. Auto layout will do all for you. But if you are using lower than IOS 8, you need to calculate cell height.

For IOS 8:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

And add below code in your controller:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Where `estimatedRowHeight` should be max height which can be for your cell.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the height of the content dynamically using  `boundingRectWithSize`. 
If you have a `UILabel` which is dynamic, you can use the following :

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   /* Check Content Size and Set Height */
    CGRect answerFrame = [YOUR_LABEL.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(240.f, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"" size:14.0f]} context:nil];

    CGSize requiredSize = answerFrame.size;

    return requiredSize.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     int topPadding = cell.yourLabel.frame.origin.x;
     int bottomPadding = cell.frame.size.heigth-(topPadding+cell.yourLabel.frame.size.height);
     NSString *text = [DescArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
     CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(cell.yourLabel.frame.size.width, 9999);
     CGSize expectedSize = [text sizeWithFont:yourCell.yourLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:yourCell.yourLabel.lineBreakMode];

     return topPadding+expectedSize.height+bottomPadding;
}
```

Comment: Problem is, that I don't have only one UILabel in it. But as i see the dynamical height only works for iOS8 and above - so when I want to support iOS 8, then I've to calculate the height programmatically, am I right?

Comment: @brokedid Yes you always have to calculate height programmatically

Comment: hello. If my screen height is ~700, but the height that calculated from label is 1000, so that my label can display all text, because return height 1000 notworking