# Unable to calculate row height using constraints if size classes are enabled in project?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, ios8, adaptive-layout

I my application i have to count cell height dynamically and i support `iOS7` and `iOS8` for my app. I'm following [Ray wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout) tutorial for this purpose. After spending a whole day on this i came to know that this technique only works if `size classes` are disabled for the app.

So my question is how to calculate row height using auto layout(constraints) if `size classes` are enabled?

Comment: size class is use for support in different device and you need dynamic height, this will support  with autolayout

Comment: Yes, i'm using auto layout but i'm not getting row height if size classes are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically height calculation is working only in IOS 8 and above when you are using Constraint in your application. It is not depend on `size classes`. You can use `Constraint` without size classes too.
[Check that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336472/ios-dynamical-height-of-uitableviewcell-and-heightforrowatindexpath/31337458#31337458)

Thanks

Comment: I'm using auto layout to calculate row height but it not works if size classes are enabled. So how to calculate row height using auto layout(constraints) if size classes are enabled?

Comment: When you are using auto layout, frames can not be set. you need to set Constraint values such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339702/presenting-a-view-controller-modally-resets-the-current-view/31340210#31340210

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the row height to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in `viewDidLoad` (but I don't think it'll work with iOS 7)

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44; // need to calculate against something
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Comment: I'm able to get cell height by using auto layout and constraints(in both iOS7 and iOS8), but it only works if i disable size classes.