# Tableview not getting Xib files height

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, xib

I have created 3 custom .xib files for my tableview.
But i am not able to figure out to specify the height of each cell.

I have implemented above line in viewdidLoad()

```
tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 120
tableview.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

I have just put a uiview in each of .xib file with 4 contraints (leading, trailing, top, bottom)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

But it's not setting proper height to my cells.

its only when I hard code the value, only then it works.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }
```

How to handle this problem, as data will soon become dynamic and I can't be changing these hardcoded value.

Comment: You should play around with the content hugging / compression resistance properties of the child views.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS dynamical height of UITableViewCell and heightForRowAtIndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336472/ios-dynamical-height-of-uitableviewcell-and-heightforrowatindexpath)

Comment: I have only one uiview in each of xib file,I have set content hugging priority to 246(both horizontal and vertical). Still not happening.

Comment: you need to set a height to xib so tableView can calculate the height of row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIView has not height value by default. As you trying it this will not set the height of cell.

You can try by placing a UILabel or UIButton inside the UIView on which you have settled the 4 constraints (leading, trailing, top, bottom).

**NOTE**: UILabel or UIButton also need 4 constraints (leading, trailing, top, bottom) if you want automatic height of UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your UIView with UILabel and set number of lines to zero, Then it will automatically take the height based on the content of UILabel